# How to read data from database using multiple thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, concurrency

How can I read data from database using multiple threads, I have 16 tables in DB and I want to read data from those tables parallelly using multiple threads.

Comment: Have each thread open their own connection and do independent queries. However, I doubt if this is going to help a lot. The performance is most likely limited by I/O so you should not expect it to go N times faster with N threads.

Comment: This question is **way** to broad. Whole books are written about such subjects. Do some *real* research and you are welcome to come back with a *real* specific question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example of creating of how we can do using 2 threads and 2 tables. Like wise, you can use it for multiple tables.

Only one connection is required as we are just reading from tables not updating or inserting or deleting from tables.

```
public class ClearPoppup implements Runnable {

    Connection c;

    private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";
    private static final String DB_USER = "root";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "****";

    public ClearPoppup() {

        try {
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClearPoppup impClass = new ClearPoppup();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(impClass) {
            public void run() {

                Statement s;
                try {
                    s = impClass.c.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from user");
                    while (rs.next())
                        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + "  " + rs.getString(3));
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Statement s;
                try {
                    s = impClass.c.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from userprofile");
                    while (rs.next())
                        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + "  " + rs.getString(3));

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

1. Create a new Connection in each thread.
2. Create a connection pool and obtain connections from threads as needed.
3. Create a single connection and `synchronize` it before using in the threads. This doesnt let you read the database "in parallel" but it allows you to use the same connection across threads.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Partitioner which will divide your all data set into number of sub-group which will process by single thread.

Create individual task and execute through executorservice.

Use countdownlatch to stop the main thread till all task completed.

Use connectionpool with size comparable to threadpool.

```
public class  Partitioner {

    @Override
    public Map<String, SomeDomainObject> partition(int size) {

        Map<String, SomeDomainObject> result
                       = new HashMap<String, SomeDomainObject>();

        int range = 10;//calculate your range depending on threadsize.
        int fromId = 1;
        int toId = range;

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            SomeDomainObject value = new SomeDomainObject();
            value.setFromId(fromId);
            value.setToId(toId);
            value.setThreadName("Thread" + i);
            result.put("partition" + i, value);
            fromId = toId + 1;
            toId += range;

        }

        return result;
    }
```